# Opening Location Permission from the inside of App flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-plugin

the page i want to access from inside the app : [image]

Comment: Try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/app_settings) plugin.

Comment: Use permission_handler for this, https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: i am already using this package but it doesn't take me to this page specifecally, it opens app setting in general. @fartem

Comment: @DharaPatel permission_handler package doesn't do the required job too

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using [Geolocator Package](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator), you can open location settings as per below. You may note that this operation can only open the device `Location Permission` page, not the entire App permission manager.

```
Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
```

Comment: i need to open the app permission manager on the location tab specifcally

Comment: Unless you build your own channel to open a specific Android Intent

Comment: `Geolocator` also has an `openAppSettings()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Use this package called, [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). This will allow you to open the app settings page where you can find the location permission.

usage:

```
RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () =>  openAppSettings(),
            child: Text("Open app settings"),
          ),
```

Comment: works like a charm! everyone working with permissions should already have `permission_handler` anyway

Answer (score 2):

In `GeoLocation` Package use   `Geolocator.openAppSettings();`

Like that

```
AlertDialog(
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: Text('Back'),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (Platform.isIOS) {
                    exit(0);
                  } else {
                    SystemNavigator.pop();
                  }
                },
              ),
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                child: Text('Settings'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Geolocator.openAppSettings();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```