# How to open Location services screen from the flutter app?

Tags: flutter, service, location, settings, screen

**I want to open location service screen programmatically to turn on service.**

In the latest iOS 17 version, by default, the location service is turned off, so when opening the Flutter app, the location permission is not shown. If we use the location package, it will show the pop-up menu for system settings and privacy and turn on the location service. It is a manual process, but I want to redirect to this screen from the app, so what can I do? I don't know.

[image]

I have tried the app_setting package, but it is not working. I want a specific way to do this. How can I get this programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening Location Permission from the inside of App flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65884174/opening-location-permission-from-the-inside-of-app-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Add and import [Location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package

And Using this code to turn on location

```
 Location location = new Location();
bool ison = await location.serviceEnabled(); 
if (!ison) { //if defvice is off
  bool isturnedon = await location.requestService();
  if (isturnedon) {
      print("GPS device is turned ON");
  }else{
      print("GPS Device is still OFF");
  }
}
```